# Program sometimes doesn't run and gives me debug error

Tags: c++

It says :

> Debug Error!
>
> R6010
>   -abort() has been called

I'm not really sure what to do about it. I'm making a program that automatically generates reviews for `SliceThePie` so you don't have to take the time to come up with them.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

void type_text(const std::string& text)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < text.size(); ++i){
        cout << text[i] << flush;

        Sleep(30);
    }
}



int generateAnswers(int loop){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int firstSentence = rand() % 8 + 0;
    int descriptors1Sentence2 = rand() % 6 + 0;
    int secondSentence = rand() % 10 + 0;
    int descriptors1Sentence = rand() % 6 + 0;
    int describe1Sentence = rand() % 14 + 0;
    int punc1C = rand() % 2 + 0;

    array<int, 6> returning = { firstSentence, descriptors1Sentence2, secondSentence, descriptors1Sentence, describe1Sentence, punc1C };

    return returning[loop - 1];
}
void randGen(){
    srand(time(NULL));

    //cout << rand() % 10 + 1 << endl;
    string descriptors1[] = { "beat ", "tempo ", "instrumentals ", "synth ", "midi ", "effects "};
    string descriptors2[] = { "mix ", "sound ", "volume ", "timing ", "rhythm ", "composure " , "melody ", "chorus "};
    string describe1[] = { "amazing", "great", "mediocre", "fair", "average", "fantastic", "beautiful", "A+ worthy", "top notch", "top of the line", "one of the best", "needing work", "not the best", "lackluster" };
    string firstSen []= { "Truthfully ", "I believe " , "In my opinion, ", "In my honest opinion, ", "I honestly believe ", "I really think that ", "I think that " , "First off, " };
    string secondSen[] = { "In addition to this, ", "Additionally, ", "Also, ", "Furthermore, ", "Continuing, " , "To continue, ", "In addition to my last point, " };
    string punc1[] = { ".", "!" };

    int firstSentence = generateAnswers(1);
    int descriptors1Sentence2 = generateAnswers(2);
    int secondSentence = generateAnswers(3);
    int descriptors1Sentence = generateAnswers(4);
    int describe1Sentence = generateAnswers(5);
    int punc1C = generateAnswers(6);
    string finFirst = firstSen[firstSentence];
    string finDesc2 = descriptors1[descriptors1Sentence2];
    string finDesc1 = descriptors1[descriptors1Sentence];
    string finDescr1 = describe1[describe1Sentence];
    string punc1S = punc1[punc1C];
    string finSecond = secondSen[secondSentence];
    string Final = finFirst + "the " + finDesc1 + "was " + finDescr1 + punc1S + " " + finSecond + "the " + finDesc2 + "was ";
    cout << "Waiting for review to complete..." << endl;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    type_text(Final);
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "Review complete." << endl;

}

int main() {
    SetConsoleTitle(TEXT("Diloq v1.01"));
    randGen();
    Sleep(5000);
    return 0;
}
```

I was initially running into problems with my computer not having enough memory to run it occasionally, but I think that I've fixed that, as it doesn't happen very often anymore. Now, however, i'm getting the debug error.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: You should use a step by step debugger to locate where in your code occurs the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an out of bounds access for `secondSentence`. Its size is `7` but you generate random numbers up to `9`:

```
int secondSentence = rand() % 10
```

This can be detected by e.g. GCC's sanitizer:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -fsanitize=undefined -Og -g main.cpp && ./a.out

main.cpp:55:48: runtime error: index 8 out of bounds for type 'string [7]'
```

Comment: Thanks! Completely fixed my problem. Not happening anymore :D